# Neo4j config file changes not having an effect

Tags: ubuntu, neo4j, cypher, config

I've installed `neo4j` on ubuntu 18.04 and everything is working fine. However when I try to edit the `neo4j.config` file, it seems that the desired change is not being applied.

For example, I tried following [this answer](https://community.neo4j.com/t/create-multiple-databases-in-community-version/5025/2) to create a new database, but it failed to load the new db.

My major problem however is when using `apoc` plugin, i've followed [this guide](https://neo4j.com/docs/labs/apoc/3.4/introduction/#usage) to install and use the plugin, but whenever I try to call a procedure found [here](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/3.5/utilities/collection-list-functions/), i get the following error:

`` There is no procedure with the name `apoc.coll.intersection` registered for this database instance. Please ensure you've spelled the procedure name correctly and that the procedure is properly deployed. ``

When I use check the neo4j service status using `serivce neo4j status` I get the following:

```
   config:       /etc/neo4j
   logs:         /var/log/neo4j
   plugins:      /var/lib/neo4j/plugins
   import:       /var/lib/neo4j/import
   data:         /var/lib/neo4j/data
   certificates: /var/lib/neo4j/certificates
   run:          /var/run/neo4j
```

which shows that the config file is being read from `/etc/neo4j` which is the one I'm editing to use apoc.

I have tried to create a `config` directory under `/var/lib/neo4j/` and copied the config file into it, but that didn't seem to work either.

Any idea of what the problem may be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am sure that `/etc/neo4j/neo4j.conf` is the right configuration file. The clue about your problem is in the start of the message

> There is no *procedure* with the name `apoc.coll.intersection`

`apoc.coll.intersection` is a function.

Try this to see if the function is indeed there.

```
CALL dbms.functions() YIELD name, description
WHERE name = 'apoc.coll.intersection'
RETURN name, description
```

And try this to see the function perform.

```
RETURN apoc.coll.intersection([1,2,3],[3,4,5])
```

Comment: When i executed the first set of queries this was returned: ` "apoc.coll.intersection(first, second) - returns the unique intersection of the two lists"` which shows that the function is there. But executing your second query returned the same error i mentioned.

Comment: can you check the updated command  (ie. with the return instead of call ) ?

Comment: @logisima weirdly using return actually returned [3]. Even tho they say you have to use `CALL`. It also worked with the keyword `WITH`, seems like it's only failing with `CALL`

Comment: You need `CALL` for procedures. Bu for invoking a function, you need nothing, so a `RETURN` or `WITH` works

Answer (score 3):

Soon it may help you, if someone is using an EC2 in AWS they should take into account that it must be modified is the `neo4.template` file.

https://neo4j.com/developer/neo4j-cloud-vms/?_ga=2.268501681.1589203581.1603335877-398296120.1598816700#vm-config

Comment: Running on EC2, updating the `neo4j.template` and then running `systemctl restart neo4j` worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

For APOC procedure, the problem doesn't come from the configuration.
Did you :

- put the jar in the folder `var/lib/neo4j/plugins` ?
- is the jar readeable for the user `neo4j` ?
- is the jar compatible with your neo4j version ?

For your database creation, can you check :

- that the `neo4j` user can write in the folder `var/lib/neo4j/data/databases` ?

I'm pretty sure you have some permission issues. 
A common mistake, is to start the server in root, and then doing it with the service system (that use the `neo4j` user).

Comment: Yes I've put the jar file in the `plugins` folder. The file version is `3.5.0.7` and my neo4j version is `3.5.13`. But how do i check if the jar file is readable for the user neo4j? Or if the user `neo4j` user could write in the folder databases?

Comment: if you do a `ls -l` inside the folder  you should the owner of the files/folders, and it should be `neo4j`. Otherwsie you can do `chown -R neo4j .`  in root to change the owner of files recursively

Comment: Yes i do see the user neo4j, next to it I see adm which im guessing references admin